# Session variables can be fooled (login)?

Tags: php, security, session, authentication

IN PHP:
Is there a way for the user to fake a session variable?

Is it secure to trust in the value of a session variable for a login system?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The session data is stored on the server. Only the session id is transferred forth and back between the client and the server. Unless a server-side script messes up (or there is a bug) the client cannot change the session data directly. But you have to ensure that only the "correct" client knows the session id, as it ties this particular client to a particular session. E.g. (since you mentioned a login) use [session_regenerate_id()](http://docs.php.net/session_regenerate_id) whenever a login (attempt) is performed to prevent [session fixation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_fixation)

Answer (score 7):

Sessions are stored on your server, either in a file or in memory. The user only holds a cookie that defines the path (usually a hash of some form) to the session data on your server. Theoretically you could change the cookie to someone else's hash, but that is very, very improbable, unless you store them as files and don't delete them after they expire, in which case the probability of someone exploiting an old session would increase.

Comment: Very, very improbable, when applied over billions of transactions, can very easily become something worth worrying quite a lot about. Of course, I have no idea as to the scale of the OP's project, but it's something to consider.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.. It's called session forge/hijack.

You change the value of the session cookie until you get another user session.

Comment: +1 for pointing out session hijacking, but I must add that it doesn't change the variable on the server. It may just allow one user to pose for another. The security/likelihood of this depends on the complexity of your session IDs and how long they're valid for.

Comment: Because of the second part of the OP's question, I think this response best answers the overall question's intent.

Comment: for the sake of simplicity. let's say I have if($_SESSION['userName']=="admin) { //things for admin } else { //thing for the rest }
IT is a way to forge/hijack the userName session variable?
Why nobody talks about this???

Comment: Wow, a google search for "session forge/hijack" return this page as first result. 33 minutes after I wrote the question!!!

Comment: @The Disintegrator: We have all talked about it, we're trying to explain to you that userName as a variable is stored on the server referenced by some hash, say 'mmr3oe8e98y4tuhgdoghd89g' (I just hit random keys). Now, the actual client has a single cookie, usually called PHPSESSID, which contains that string so that the server can use it to find the data. So if someone were randomly typing strings, they could theoretically retrieve another user's session and use their userName.

Comment: @animuson for nobody I was talking about OUTSIDE this. Whenever I see any article talking about sessions, there is no reference to session hijaking.
It's bad to try to do a fact check before trusting the security of a system?

Comment: -1 this is not a real attack.  Normal session id's are very large and would take trillions of requests to obtain another valid session.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid storing session data in the server, you can [sign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature) the content you want to protect from change, before storing it on session, and then validate just after retrieval from session. In PHP this process is [reasonable simple](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9727841/414058) and eliminates server storage issues.

Notice that this does not protect session data from being visualized. If you need this protection, you can still avoid server storage by using safe encryption. Just beware that virtually every encryption scheme based on key size can be broken on near future. So if you need to protect your session data for say, 5 years, the secure choice of key and algorithm might create performance issues.