# how to digitally sign a file in PHP

Tags: php, digital-signature

I made a **user** table in my DB with different columns for holding users' info. Also I have added two columns **public_key** and **private_key**.
When a user registers, his info will be inserted to the table. plus I am using:

```
// Create the keypair
$res=openssl_pkey_new();

// Get private key
openssl_pkey_export($res, $privatekey);

// Get public key
$publickey=openssl_pkey_get_details($res);
$publickey=$publickey["key"];
```

to create a random key pair and give it to user so that every user has a key pair.
I want my users to have digital-signature ability, so when they upload a file they sign it.

I decided to sign a sample file(msg.txt) first to see if I can and then proceed. It looks straight forward:

```
openssl_pkcs7_sign("msg.txt", "signed.txt", "signing_cert.pem",
array("private_key.pem", "mypassphrase"),
array()
);
```

The problem is: what are signing_cert.pem and private_key.pem ? I pasted my generated public key in signing_cert.pem and the private one in private_key.pem, but I see this error:

```
Warning: openssl_pkcs7_sign() [function.openssl-pkcs7-sign]: error getting 
private key in /home/ofathian/public_html/msc/ebook/mine/assymetric-test.php 
on line 40
```

Any opinion is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I came to conclusion of why not make my own digital signing function.

digital signing algorithm works like this: 
first the plain text is hashed then it is encypted by user's private key, then the result 
is concatenated with the plain text.

pseudo code:

```
return [input + encrypt(md5(input),private_key)]
```

For verifying: Input is splitted to plain text and signature. then signature is decrypted 
using public key. Then the result is compared to the hash of the plain text and if they 
are equal it means the signature is verified.

pseudo code:

```
explode(input) --> plain_text , signature
if( decrypt(signature,public_key) == md5(plain_text) ) then signature is trusted
```

Now the real PHP code which I have tested and currently using:

```
function sign($cleartext,$private_key)
{
    $msg_hash = md5($cleartext);
    openssl_private_encrypt($msg_hash, $sig, $private_key);
    $signed_data = $cleartext . "----SIGNATURE:----" . $sig;
    return mysql_real_escape_string($signed_data);
}

function verify($my_signed_data,$public_key)
{
    list($plain_data,$old_sig) = explode("----SIGNATURE:----", $my_signed_data);
    openssl_public_decrypt($old_sig, $decrypted_sig, $public_key);
    $data_hash = md5($plain_data);
    if($decrypted_sig == $data_hash && strlen($data_hash)>0)
        return $plain_data;
    else
        return "ERROR -- untrusted signature";
}
```

Comment: I would suggest to return only a bool since that is what function name suggests.

Comment: Interesting, but what if `----SIGNATURE:----` appears inside the data?

Answer (score 1):

signing_cert.pem and private_key.pem are the certificates you use to sign that file.
So if you have them stored in DB, you need to dump them to files called signing_cert.pem and private_key.pem respectivelly.

The error you are getting is that openssl tries to load those files, and since they do not exists then it claims.

If you write those files to harddisk from your DB, plase TAKE IN MIND:

1. Do NOT store it in any public accesible folder (avoid DOCUMENT_ROOT AND temp directory). Specially for the private key to avoid security issues.
2. Remove them when you've done.

Also, you could, instead of having those certificates in DB, have them stored in some folder for each user, to prevent dumping to a file when signing. Of course, that folder should not be accesible to anyone.

More info: [PHP openssl_pkc7_sign](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkcs7-sign.php)

Comment: Do you think it was right that I pasted my generated public key in signing_cert.pem and the private one in private_key.pem then?

Comment: signing_cert.pem looks like: 
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY----- zzz...zzz... -----END PUBLIC KEY-----
and
private_key.pem looks like:
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- ..z... -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
In the private key file shouldn't it be DSA instead of RSA? (Digital Signature Alg.)

Comment: If you pasted those files, then check file permissions (and for the next time, do it outside WWW root).

Comment: Unfortunatelly, I don't know that much about keys to answer your last comment, to know if it should or not DSA, but I've seen many RSA signatures for that purpose, so it should work well with RSA.

Comment: I changed permission of both to 0777 but no success

Comment: Then it seems that without the password for the private key, it can't access to private key to sign. Double check it, and if it does not work try removing passphrase (to test): `openssl rsa -in private.key -out private.key.nopass` or something similar. Hope it helps

Comment: thanks stormByte but still no success. I got frustrated so made my own signing function. what do you think about it? any security threat that catch your eyes?

Comment: I am not an expert in this area but as long as private key is isolated enough from public access it seems  a good approach.

Comment: @Omidoo as I have seen in the URI I posted above, could you try setting ‘array("file://private_key.pem", "passphrase")‘ as parameter for private key and retest your original solution?

Comment: I have also read that I should store signatures in BLOB and not TEXT, so I gave both a try and they both work just fine. any idea?