# PHP OpenSSL asymmetric encryption -- is it really this simple?

Tags: php, encryption, openssl

I'm building an application in PHP where I'd like to use asymmetric encryption for exchanging messages between two users.

Ignoring key management and other external factors for the sake of this question, is it really this simple?

```
$config = array(
    "digest_alg" => "sha512",
    "private_key_bits" => 4096,
    "private_key_type" => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA,
);

$res = openssl_pkey_new($config);
openssl_pkey_export($res, $privKey);
$pubKey = openssl_pkey_get_details($res);
$pubKey = $pubKey["key"];

openssl_public_encrypt('this was encrypted with the public key', $secret, $pubKey);
openssl_private_decrypt($secret, $decrypted, $privKey);

echo "Decrypted message: $decrypted
```

Comment: Yes!. Maybe you can use openssl_verify to see if it was sent by who you think it was.

Comment: Honestly, I think you can get even simpler than OpenSSL makes it. eg. with phpseclib: http://pastebin.com/5G8pazdC

Comment: You also might want to check out `openssl_seal()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to digitally sign a file in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9707794/how-to-digitally-sign-a-file-in-php)

Answer (score 5):

> Ignoring key management and other external factors for the sake of this question, is it really this simple?

Getting code that *works* in general, for short inputs? Yes.

Getting code that works *securely*, for inputs of any length? Don't we all wish! But, no.

For fun, try encrypting an entire blog post with this code. It'll fail hard if your blog post is significantly longer than a tweet.

```
<?php
$config = array(
    "digest_alg" => "sha512",
    "private_key_bits" => 4096,
    "private_key_type" => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA,
);

$res = openssl_pkey_new($config);
openssl_pkey_export($res, $privKey);
$pubKey = openssl_pkey_get_details($res);
$pubKey = $pubKey["key"];

$message = file_get_contents('https://paragonie.com/blog/2018/04/protecting-rsa-based-protocols-against-adaptive-chosen-ciphertext-attacks/source');
openssl_public_encrypt($message, $secret, $pubKey);
var_dump($secret);
```

This will output `NULL`, because the message size is [significantly longer than what RSA allows](https://paragonie.com/blog/2016/12/everything-you-know-about-public-key-encryption-in-php-is-wrong#rsa-ecb).

You might be tempted to break your message up into chunks and then decrypt independently. Messages can be dropped or reordered at will and it will still decrypt. It's not semantically secure.

Furthermore, the default padding mode (PKCS #1 v1.5) is vulnerable to [an attack that dates back to 1998](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/12688/can-you-explain-bleichenbachers-cca-attack-on-pkcs1-v1-5).

So if you want to use asymmetric cryptography in PHP *without* severe limitations or being vulnerable to a plethora of side-channel attacks, you end up needing to do one of the following:

1. [Use libsodium](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/09/how-to-safely-implement-cryptography-in-any-application) (PHP 7.2+).

   - Specifically, you'll want to use [`sodium_crypto_box_seal()` and `sodium_crypto_box_seal_open()`](https://paragonie.com/blog/2017/06/libsodium-quick-reference-quick-comparison-similar-functions-and-which-one-use#crypto-box-seal). You don't even have to know what these functions *do* to use them securely. It's that easy.
2. Design a hybrid AES+RSA cryptosystem that uses a secure padding mode (RSAES-OAEP) or implements [the Anti-BB'98 dance](https://paragonie.com/blog/2018/04/protecting-rsa-based-protocols-against-adaptive-chosen-ciphertext-attacks#rsa-anti-bb98).

So, in essence: Yes, your example code is "all you need to do" to get code that works. However, making RSA secure is a Herculean effort that cannot be trivialized.

In closing, when in doubt, hire a cryptographer.